# Call to a member function build() on boolean error in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, urlhelper

I am using the below code in my Controller file to generate full site URL

`$this->Url->build(['controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'], true);`.

But I am getting a "Call to a member function build() on boolean" error. The reason why I am not using

`Router::URL(['controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index']);`

is I don't want a relative URL. Can't I use Url builder in the controller?

Comment: Helpers are for views, not controllers. `Router::url()` will give you the absolute/full URL when passing `true` as the second argument, so you might need to explain a little more detailed how the snippet you're showing there doesn't give you the desired result.

Comment: Thank you @ndm. I wasn't passing ````true```` in ````Router::URL````. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the main reason of your Error is wrong name of Controller.

First,[Name Conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/intro/conventions.html#controller-conventions) says

> "Controller class names are plural, PascalCased, and end in Controller. UsersController and ArticleCategoriesController are both examples of conventional controller names."

so your file name must be like `HomesController.php`. Next the Class name should be like this `HomesController`.

Secondly, for CakePHP character size matters. If you want build URL to your controller you have to do like this

`$this->Url->build(['controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'index'], true);`

Where controller name should be capitalize.

[More about building URL in CakePHP](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/url.html)